# SVG textures for 3D game objects in Unity?

Tags: unity, textures

Is there a way to make textures using vector graphics and use it for 3d models so that textures would be object size independent and won't get blurry?

Comment: "SVG" specifically, likely not. But if there's a specific visual look you want to achieve, there might be a way to achieve it with a combination of distance fields and shader math. Try editing your question to include an example of the texture effect you want to achieve, and we can suggest means to approximate it.

Comment: Unity does have an SVG to Texture converter package https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@1.0/manual/index.html

Comment: @Red1Monster note that this imports SVGs as collections of geometry to draw flat, not as a texture that can be mapped onto the surface of a 3D model. Converting an SVG to a raster that can be sampled for rendering a 3D model would lose the resolution independence property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible? Sure, all you would need to do is implement a custom pixel shader which can renders SVG files instead of using an albedo texture.

Is it a good idea? Likely not, because vector graphics are usually not rendered pixel-by-pixel but shape-by-shape. GPUs are not optimized for that. I doubt you would manage to achieve a passable performance, even with very trivial SVGs.

It would very likely be a better idea to just use higher resolution textures. If you want to use vector graphics just to save file space (would of course only work if your textures are of an aesthetic which is expressed well in vector graphics) you could render the SVGs to textures at game start.

Comment: Well, the thing would be that the pixel textures would need to be cached, thresholds defined when to really regenerate, e.g. based on what healthy eyes really see, and for sure, to fall back to a similar resolution texture already cached, until a new one is calculated.
I have the same challenge right now for drawing schematics.