# Is it possible to use an SVG as a texture for a 3d object?

Tags: unity

I'm using the Vector Graphics plugin for Unity 2019 and am able to drag an SVG into the scene. However, I am not able to drag it onto a 3d object as I am with a PNG. My goal is to make 3d cubes that rotate with a particular icon on each side of the cube.

I came across this related post: [SVG textures for 3D game objects in Unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151887/svg-textures-for-3d-game-objects-in-unity) but I'd like to make sure there haven't been any advancements since 2017 in this area. Also, would it be possible to add an SVG to a material? I can't figure out a way to do it but I am not very experienced with Unity.

Comment: As we told the last user who asked this, SVG is not the tool you want to use here. If you want crisp vector-like icons drawn on a mesh at a wide range of zoom levels, signed distance field techniques are a much more practical means to that end. Please consider editing your question to ask about the problem you want to solve (eg. "draw icons on a cube") not about your guessed-at solution of applying an SVG to a 3D object's material, which will not work. Not now, not next year, and I'd be reasonably confident saying "not ever." It's just not what SVG is for, nor how 3D pipelines work.

Comment: Thanks @DMGregory. It's good to get confirmation here. Signed distance fields is a bit over my head but I'll look into it. I put this in my post, but I guess I'll reiterate: My goal is to make 3d cubes that rotate with a particular icon on each side of the cube. Ignoring the rotation part which is out of the scope of this question, would you suggest drag and dropping PNG images onto the objects as the best solution to getting an icon to appear on every face of a 3d cube? Thank you.

Comment: I did not ask you to repeat yourself in a comment, I asked you to edit your question so it's not committing the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Well, the real reason I posted this question is to get an answer to the question, "Is it possible to add an SVG to a 3d object?", which you've answered. I only put the goal in there so other readers can know what my intent/end goal is. Go ahead and make your comment into a full answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: In that case it's a duplicate of an existing question and we can close it. In general, "how can I achieve this game feature" questions yield much more useful answers than "is it possible to achieve this game feature in this specific way" so I'd advise to lean toward the former for future questions.

Comment: Got it - thank you! We originally thought to go with PNGs but our designers (who don't know Unity) asked us to use SVG instead, so I wanted to know if it was possible. Appreciate the advice.